# How to return datatable in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to Vb.net.

I got a task to upgrade a website from Vs 2008 to VS 2012.
I would really appreciate if I get some help from here.
I have posted my code, I don't understand what is dbaccess in that, and because of that, I am getting many errors

```
Imports System.Data
Imports Authenciate
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Functions
    Enum enumType
        eProject
        eNonproject
    End Enum

    Enum enumTimeFormat
        HH_MM_SS
        HH_MM
    End Enum

Public Function CrossTabCustomerWise(ByVal FromDate As String, ByVal ToDate As String, ByVal DeptId As Long, Optional ByVal Empcode As String = "") As Object
 Dim strSQL As New System.Text.StringBuilder '= "SELECT * FROM t3_viewSummary where logdate between " & "'" & FromDate & "' AND '" & ToDate & "' "
        Dim strQuery As New System.Text.StringBuilder


'strQuery.Append(" SELECT Customer FROM t3_forCrossTable ")
 strQuery.Append(" where Shiftdate between ''" & FromDate & "'' AND ''" & ToDate & "'' ")
        If Empcode <> "" Then
            strQuery.Append(" And EmpCode = ''" & Empcode & "''")
        End If
        If DeptId <> 0 Then
            strQuery.Append(" And DeptID = " & DeptId & " ")
        End If


        strSQL.Append(" EXEC t3_crosstab ")
        strSQL.Append(" ' ")
        strSQL.Append(" SELECT Customer FROM t3_forCrossTable ")
        strSQL.Append(strQuery)
        strSQL.Append(" GROUP BY Customer order by customer ', ")
        strSQL.Append(" 'sum((Hrs * 60) + mins)', 'substring(cast(ShiftDate as varchar(20)),1,11) ',  ")
        strSQL.Append(" '")
        strSQL.Append("(")
        strSQL.Append(" SELECT Customer,Shiftdate FROM t3_forCrossTable ")
        strSQL.Append(strQuery)
        strSQL.Append(")")
        strSQL.Append("t3_forCrossTable")
        strSQL.Append("' ")



        Return (New DbAccess).ReturnDataTable(strSQL.ToString, strConnAsAdmin)
    End Function
```

Comment: From a brief look at your code, you're going to be getting several errors; I'd recommend working through the errors in order of simplicity and then posting specific questions about each error you cannot solve yourself.  When you post specific questions, be sure to include the code and the specific error.  Also, you can try reducing the complexity of your code to the minimum necessary to replicate errors as that will help people help you.

Comment: Check the references: `DbAccess` sounds like a helper type, probably defined in a referenced assembly. Also note: you should (I would prefer "must") clean up that SQL generation: use `DbParameter` objects to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: There is no type Dbaccess defined in this project, I have no idea y they have used this word to return datatable.